# Writing extension for Alfred, output to window?

Tags: macos, plugins, alfred

I want to make an extension for the application Alfred, and I want to have the output go to the app window. To understand what I mean (assuming you have Alfred), enter "2+3" in the Alfred text box. You will see it says "5" as a result item, and it can be copied to the clipboard by pressing Return. Is there a way to do this with Extensions? Growling a result is getting annoying, and impractical 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. It is more like a workaround since you can't chain outputs to inputs at present, but it's an "official" workaround.

You can simply use an osascript (Apple script) as an output in which you call Alfred and insert your `{query}` as an argument into an input:

```
tell application "Alfred 2" to search "keyword {query}"
```

If you use the same keyword as in your original input you will have to distinguish somehow if your argument is typed in or automatically inserted by your output. You can also use a new input with a different keyword.

Have a look here: [Alfred forums](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1283-how-to-script-filters-reusing-a-single-script-filter-or-chaining-multiple-together/)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is have text in Alfred's text entry box, then @Blacklight's answer will serve you well. If you want to have results displayed for a custom search, you will need to use one of the many [Alfred libraries](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/2030-workflow-libraries-and-helpers/). If you want to script Alfred beyond searching some text (as in @Blacklight's answer), you should look into `External Triggers` in the newest versions of Alfred.